"Add row into table" in Power Automate is being inconsistent
Sometimes this flow correctly appends the rows from my SharePoint list to the newly created excel file, sometimes it doesn't. The only way I can force it to append to the new excel file is by deleting 'Add a row into a table' and readding it, there must be another way. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
Get Items
Get File Content
Initialize variable
Create File
Create Table
Get File Content
Apply to Each, Get Rows, For Each, Add a Row into a Table
I added a 'Delay' action for 5 Seconds before 'Apply to Each' and it works a little more often. I want the new excel file to be appended with values in its Table every time.
I have a compose action after 'Add a row into a table' that takes the output of 'Add a row into a table' that always looks good even if the new excel file doesn't have anything appended in the table, can anyone assist me in other ways to debug this so people can help?
